# declaring an extern C function on template instantiation

Tags: c++

I'm working on an MCU (STM32F4). 
In the current system, all the interrupts handlers are declared as weak symbols in a link file, and if we want to use one, we just declare a function with the same name in C and it replaces the weak one at link time.

I'm trying to convert my system to C++, I envision a system where instantiating a certain interrupt type would declare the corresponding C function in the module.

I have no clue how to achieve that considering that extern "C" is forbidden for member functions.

any idea or alternative ?
My aim is to try to statically check some things and try to use some modern C++ in the field.

here is the current situation in C.
I have a assembly file with this thing in it:

```
g_pfnVectors:
.word  _estack
.word  Reset_Handler
(...)
.word  SysTick_Handler
(...)
/*******************************************************************************
*
* Provide weak aliases for each Exception handler to the Default_Handler. 
* As they are weak aliases, any function with the same name will override 
* this definition.
* 
*******************************************************************************/
(...)
.weak      SysTick_Handler
.thumb_set SysTick_Handler,Default_Handler
```

in my C code, I have that :

```
main() {
    (...)
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / cncMemory.parameters.clockFrequency);

    while (1);
}
void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    cncMemory.tick++;
}
```

And I envision something like:

```
int main() {
    MCU<mySystickHandler, ...> mcu;
    mcu.start();
}

static void mySystickHandler(void) {
    cncMemory.tick++;
}
```

or something approaching (probably without the still global function, but I try to separate the problems).

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your question completely, a bit of code can surely help. About member functions, [you can actually instantiate classes present in shared objects](http://wanderinghorse.net/computing/papers/classloading_cpp.html). Its essentially a hack around having a single function which creates and returns objects from inside the SO. About template, to the extent I understand your question, I do not think that's possible.

Comment: I added some existing code, and a possible future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of nothing standard for that.

If you want to stay in the language, you'll have to look at extensions as compilers have provided pragmas and attributes to control such things for a long time.  In the case of gcc, [asm labels](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) seems designed for that problem.  I've not used it and I've the *a priori* that it can't be used with templates excepted perhaps for explicit specializations.

The alternative is obviously playing with linker level tricks.

- AFAIK a weak symbol doesn't make an object file providing it to be extracted from a static library if it is the only symbol provided by the object.  You could arrange that the object file providing from C to your template provide also another unique symbol which is needed by the instantiation you want.
- Linker scripts have a lot of power and if things haven't changed too much since the last time I took care of embedded systems (that's so long ago that they must changed, I just don't know if they have changed in that aspect) custom linker scripts are still pretty much mandatory in that field.